# How to use select inputs with Crowd HTML for mturk

Tags: html, mechanicalturk

I'm trying to set up a question with a select/dropdown for answers on mechanical turk, using Crowd HTML.

This is what I've got so far, but it doesn't give me a dropdown feature when testing, and it just appears as an ordinary text input. The documentation says this:

***type***
Takes a string to set the HTML5 input-type behavior for the input. Examples include file and date.

So based on this I think it should work but clearly no dice. Any ideas on how to do this? Thank you

```
<crowd-input name="qualificationType" type="select" required>
                <option value="">High School</option>
                <option value="">Some College</option>
                <option value="">Associate Degree</option>
                <option value="">Bachelor's Degree</option>
                <option value="">Professional Degree</option>
                <option value="">Master's Degree</option>
                <option value="">Doctorate Degree</option>        
            </crowd-input>
```

Answer (score 1):

A dropdown list is a select element, which you can use in mturk. Change what you have to:

```
<select name="qualificationType" required>
            <option value="">High School</option>
            <option value="">Some College</option>
            <option value="">Associate Degree</option>
            <option value="">Bachelor's Degree</option>
            <option value="">Professional Degree</option>
            <option value="">Master's Degree</option>
            <option value="">Doctorate Degree</option>        
        </select>
```

And it should work